# Create Ad Control that can play anything like PPT,Flash File, Image or Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to create A Ad control that display ADVERTISMENTS, Ad can be anything like PPT,Image,Flash File or Video, is there any way that all these things can be displayed one by one in a WEB page.

Comment: you can try orangebox v3 http://orangebox.davidpaulhamilton.net/
let me know if this helped

Comment: No actually , My problem is i want to display a series of ads on a portion of a screen, where for random ads would be displayed, like for 5 seconds it will display a image file, then flash file,then video file, then flash, and then PPT and so on.

Comment: you can create all your slides and set timer then display one div and hide other divs or create multiview it will show only one view at a time. I assume you can show ppt flashfile image or video seperately.let me know if this helps

Comment: yes  skhurams this is the way i'm thinking of, thanks for your reply, but still i wonder if there can be any other way that i can show these file altogether. thanks for your support.

Comment: You can also use any jquery slider dont use sliding effect just use fade effect. Still if you need help let me know.